# how do i get id of these JSON response in angular

Tags: angularjs, json

```
<label ng-repeat="role in roles">
<input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="user.roles" data-checklist-value="role"> {{role.text}}
</label>

  $scope.roles = [
    'guest', 
    'user', 
    'customer', 
    'admin'
  ];

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                  <h5>G2 Result</h5>
                  <pre>{{user.roles|json}}</pre>
                </div>
```

i used checklist-model js if i printing the roles Getting below reponse but i want to get id of below these json response

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "text": "user"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "text": "customer"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "text": "admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "guest"
  }
]
```

how do i get id of these JSON response in angular

I wish to pass id into data-checklist-model

Comment: Why not just write `data-checklist-model="{{role.id}}"` ?

Comment: I did then user.roles|json does not work

Comment: Is the `roles` array placed in `user` object? If so, you need to apply the namespacing in `ng-repeat` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roles` is a `JSONArray`. You need to provide index to get the `id` of concerned `JSONObject`.

Like:

```
user.roles[0].id or user.roles[1].id
```

If you want to get `id` of all `JSONObjects` then you need to use `ng-repeat` and iterate this array to get concerned `JSONObject`.

Like:

```
<div ng-repeat="role in user.roles">             
    <h2>{{role.id}}</h2>
</div>
```